# NativeScript ExoPlayer-Wrapper native library implementation

Tags: android, nativescript

I am trying to implement [ExoPlayer-Wrapper](https://github.com/Pulimet/ExoPlayer-Wrapper) for NativeScript Android like this:

I have created a custom view using `Placeholder`

```
<Placeholder (creatingView)="createNativeView($event)"></Placeholder>
```

In TS:

```
public createNativeView(args: CreateViewEventData) {

    let exoPlayerView = new com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView(args.context);

    let mExoPlayerHelper = new net.alexandroid.utils.exoplayerhelper.ExoPlayerHelper.Builder(args.context, exoPlayerView)
        .setUiControllersVisibility(true)
        .setAutoPlayOn(true)
        .setVideoUrls("http://cdn-fms.rbs.com.br/vod/hls_sample1_manifest.m3u8")
        .setTagUrl("http://google.com")
        .createAndPrepare();

    args.view = exoPlayerView;
}
```

But I didn't get any success or error message. APP got exit instantly after start. Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my mistake https://github.com/Pulimet/ExoPlayer-Wrapper/blob/5476adf07e71105a009a6fc643daeb54b7a1f953/exoplayerhelper/src/main/java/net/alexandroid/utils/exoplayerhelper/ExoPlayerHelper.java#L204

'`String[] urls`'. So, url will be array type like this:

```
.setVideoUrls(["http://cdn-fms.rbs.com.br/vod/hls_sample1_manifest.m3u8"])
```